# 404 not found on DELETE & PUT methods, but route exist - Laravel & vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I don't know why and how, but when I'm trying to do a PUT or DELETE request, it display "404 not found" even tho the route exist and that everything worked before...

My project is base on Laravel & Vuejs

The GET requests are working, I can see the views, I can even make a POST request to store something in my database, but as soon as I want to DELETE or PUT anything, it fails, can't find the route.

[image: Route list]

I tried those commands

- `php artisan optimize`
- `php artisan route:cache`
- `php artisan view:clear`
- `php artisan config:cache`

But that doesn't work. We can see the routes in `php artisan route:list` command tho...
All the controllers exist and their functions. I tried to change the name of them, change the route url and a bunch of other stuff, but still not working. Like I said, erverything was working last time that I tried those types of request. We can also see clairly in the web inspector that the URL request is good.

[image]

> routes/dashboard.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified',])->group(function () {
    Route::controller(DashboardController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'Index')->name('dashboard');
    });
    Route::controller(SensorController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::prefix('/sensor')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/', 'Index')->name('sensor');
            Route::post('/store', 'Store')->name('sensor.store');
            Route::put('/update/{sensor}', 'Update')->name('sensor.update');
            Route::delete('/destroy/{sensor}', 'Destroy')->name('sensor.destroy');
        });
    });
});
```

> SensorController.php

```
public function Update(Request $request, Sensor $sensor)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'max:20',
                Rule::unique(Sensor::class)->ignore($sensor->id)
            ],
            'limits_range' => [
                'required',
                'array',
                'min:2',
                'max:2'
            ]
        ]);

        $sensor->name = $request->name;
        $sensor->limits_range = JSON_ENCODE($request->limits_range);
        $sensor->active = $request->active;
        $sensor->update();

        return redirect()->route('sensor');
    }
```

I really don't understand what's happening, thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `Sensor` type hint in your `Store` function signature. Do you still get a `404`? Laravel will respond with a `404` on valid routes if when attempting route model binding, it can't resolve the model.

Comment: Well, If I remove the `Sensor $sensor` in the Update params for example, the route will be ok for some reason..

Comment: Don't remove the parameter entirely, just the type hint (i.e. `Store(Request $request, $sensor)`). Obviously the rest of your function will not work as intended, however, if you get a different error response and not a `404`, this suggests Laravel can't find the related model (`2` in this case).

Comment: Okok! Now It seems the solve the route problem. Why is that happening? And how can I replace the `Sensor $sensor` in my function? So that everything else work as before? Sorry I'm a begginer in Laravel & vue. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: This isn't a `Vue` issue it's a `Laravel` issue, specifically Laravel can't resolve a model from your route model binding. Assuming you have a record in the database with an `id` of `2` it _should_ work. However, if you have changed the [primary key](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys) for the model, the `route` will require that key rather than its `id`.

Comment: Oooooh god, ok, you just made me realise my mistake, I did change the primary key in the modal, that was the issue.. I really feel stoopid lol

Comment: But can I still tell Laravel to use another primary key but retrieve the object by the ID anyway? I don't know if it's clear. Because the serial number of the sensor is like also a primary key so..

Comment: Yes. You can configure route model binding to search on multiple fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is due to the [primary key](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys) of the `Sensor` model having been changed from `id` to another column within the database.

This means that when the `{sensor}` parameter passed to the route is *not* a value found in the models configured `primary key` column, Laravel will return a `404 - Not Found` response.

If you want to use multiple keys for route model binding, you can configure the service in the `RouteServiceProvider`.

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('sensor', function($value) {
        return Sensor::where('serial_number', $value)->orWhere(function ($query) use ($value) {
            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                $query->where('id', $value)
            }
        })->firstOrFail()
    });

    parent::boot();
}
```

The above will attempt to find a record in the database where the `serial_number` column has the value of the `{sensor}` URI parameter. If not found it will attempt to find a record based on the `id` column (if `{sensor}` is numeric.