# Trying to show the current signed in users profile. What am i doing wrong | Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Trying to show the current signed in user's profile. What am i doing wrong.This is the function on the controller. I'm using Laravel 9

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    return view('users.index', with('user', $user));
}
```

This is the routes

```
    Route::resource('users', UsersController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

And my generic layout page

```
<x-dropdown-item href="/users/{{ auth()->user()->username }}" >Account</x-dropdown-item>
```

When i click the link i get user not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're utilising route model binding which unless configured otherwise, requires you to provide a route with a model `id`. You're providing it with a `username`, so Laravel is throwing a `404` because it can't locate the relevant record in the database.

If you replace `username` with `id`, the binding should work.

```
<x-dropdown-item href="/users/{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
    Account
</x-dropdown-item>
```

Comment: @kristitanellari If you want to change how route model binding works with other database fields, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73847353/281278).

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine. Are you sure you have a route with username, resource routes are using id.

Comment: So I have to do auth()->user()->id?

Answer (score 0):

To access model like that you need to specify id in the route like:
/users/{id}

However what you are trying to do here is access the logged in user model which you can access with the facade `Auth::user();`

You can access the user any time any where in the code and there is no need to pass it to an anchor link unless sending to an external system.